# How to call the UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera continuously

Tags: ios, iphone

I have the following problem when developing on iOS.  I want to achieve that when I'm clicking on a tabbar item the camera shows up.  Now that isn't so hard but the problem is this happens once.  So when I click on another tabbar item and click back to the camera item, the camera doesn't show up again.

I think this is because when you click on cancel the UIImagePickerController dismisses and doesn't initialize again.  How can I solve this problem, that when I'm clicking on the tabbar item the camara will always show up.

```
class CameraViewController: UIViewController, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate,UINavigationControllerDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!
let imagePicker:UIImagePickerController!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad();
    self.loadCamera();
}


func loadCamera(){

        if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(
            UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.Camera) {

                imagePicker = UIImagePickerController();
                imagePicker.delegate = self;
                imagePicker.sourceType = .Camera;

                presentViewController(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)

        }
    }

    func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [NSObject : AnyObject]) {
        imagePicker.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
        imageView.image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage


    }


}
```

Comment: Please show us the code of your view controller handling the UIImagePickerController.

Comment: @SanjeetSuhag see edit in original post.

Comment: Are you initializing the class CameraViewController when you click on the camera tab item.

Comment: @Navid how are you dismissing the camera?

Comment: @NitheeshGeorge no i don't initialized the class because in my storyboard when i'm selecting my ViewController i say that it should use the CameraViewController Class that should do the stuff i think doesn't it?

Comment: @IxPaka yes i dismissing the camera as u can in the method ImagePickerController.

Answer (score 0):

You can directly present the UIImagePickerController from the UITabbarController's derived class.

or

Make UIImagePickerController a subview of your CameraViewController and present the CameraViewController from UITabbarController's derived class.

Comment: Hou can i achieve the seccond approach? Because the tabbar Items are created in the Appdelegate. Should i use a sepparate UITabbarController class?

Comment: Use separate UITabBar for your needs and hide the tabbar in UITabarController. Then handle the events of your second UITabar and switch between the UITabbarController's view using UITabBarController selectedIndex property. When the Camera TabbarItem is tapped show the CameraController from the rootViewController.

Comment: I really don't understand the point.. why should i use two UITabbars ? can you please provide me a example?. I just want to have 1 UIItabbar and in that Tabbar i want the Camera item to be clickable constantly and not just once like i have implemented now.